# plt.yticks not working properly - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working on a project in unity and from a **C#** script I'm calling a **Python** script to plot some values on a graph using **matplotlib**, everything works fine except for the **yticks** on the graph.
The values that are going to be plotted are floats within 0.5 and 5.5 circa, here is the graph for reference:
[image: graph]

what I've done to set the yticks is the following:

```py
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.yticks([0, 2, 4, 5])
plt.xlabel("frame")
plt.ylabel("distance")
plt.show()
```

As you can see instead of having ticks in the specified positions `[0, 2, 4, 5]` it displays 4 ticks all around 0.5. It looks like no matter what array I pass to `yticks()`, it only takes the `len()` of it and puts the exact number of ticks but in the wrong places, i guess the first n-th values of y axis

**Python version: 3.8.8, Matplotlib version: 3.4.1**

Many thanks to anyone who will help.

**EDIT: minimal reproducible example.
The image above is generated using 600 values, in the example below only 50 values are used so the graph is different but the ytick problem remains.**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

y = ['0.5356', '0.5356', '0.5615', '0.5509', '0.4958', '0.4944', '0.5056', '0.5512', '0.6314', 
     '0.7394', '0.8761', '1.0320', '1.2066', '1.3692', '1.5456', '1.7262', '1.9124', '2.0955',
     '2.2262', '2.2424', '2.2363', '2.2285', '2.1811', '2.1159', '2.0400', '1.9590', '1.8685',
     '1.7614', '1.6517', '1.5322', '1.3897', '1.2642', '1.1080', '0.9256', '0.8161', '0.6624',
     '0.5240', '0.3763', '0.2361', '0.1649', '0.2151', '0.3441', '0.5065', '0.6785', '0.8355',
     '1.0118', '1.1708', '1.3253', '1.4888', '1.6247']
x = [i for i in range(1, 51)]

# plotting
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.yticks([0, 2, 4, 5])
plt.xlabel("frame")
plt.ylabel("distance")
plt.show()
```

graph should be like this:

[image: 50frames]

Comment: How are you reading the data in? Are you sure they are floats? Creating a [mcve] will make it easier for us to help

Comment: basically I'm calling the python script from C# with Process.start() and i'm passing values as arguments, yes i'm sure they are floats. I'll try to create a minimal reproducible example and edit it in the question btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i'm an idiot.
As usual it was the stupidest thing i could have ever done.
values are not floats but strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly set the tick frequency like this :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

y = ['0.5356', '0.5356', '0.5615', '0.5509', '0.4958', '0.4944', '0.5056', '0.5512', '0.6314', 
     '0.7394', '0.8761', '1.0320', '1.2066', '1.3692', '1.5456', '1.7262', '1.9124', '2.0955',
     '2.2262', '2.2424', '2.2363', '2.2285', '2.1811', '2.1159', '2.0400', '1.9590', '1.8685',
     '1.7614', '1.6517', '1.5322', '1.3897', '1.2642', '1.1080', '0.9256', '0.8161', '0.6624',
     '0.5240', '0.3763', '0.2361', '0.1649', '0.2151', '0.3441', '0.5065', '0.6785', '0.8355',
     '1.0118', '1.1708', '1.3253', '1.4888', '1.6247']
y = [float(i) for i in y]
x = [i for i in range(1, 51)]

# plotting
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(y), max(y)+1, 1.0))
plt.xlabel("frame")
plt.ylabel("distance")
plt.show()
```

[image]